# Ubuntu can't detect external 4TB Seagate hard drive after accidently formatting and stopping immediately

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, restore, disk-formatting

I used sudo `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb` to format  a flash drive (I didn't notice /`sd*`) but accidentally my Seagate external hard disk (`/dev/sdb`) started being formatted and immediately after few seconds I cancelled that command. I was still able to use the hard disk as it was already mounted to my Ubuntu machine, but when I unmounted it and tried to access it Ubuntu didn't detect it anymore.

Results of `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/backup`:

```
mount: /media/backup: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Results of `sudo fdisk -l # pasting the last few paragraphs`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000DM003-1ER1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x7f7a3175

Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048  199999487  199997440  95.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       200001534 1953523711 1753522178 836.1G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       200001536 1953523711 1753522176 836.1G 83 Linux

Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.65 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Disk model: BUP Portable    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Results of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             12G     0   12G   0% /dev
tmpfs           2.4G  1.8M  2.4G   1% /run
/dev/sda1        94G  9.4G   80G  11% /
tmpfs            12G  197M   12G   2% /dev/shm
tlsblkmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            12G     0   12G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop2       32M   32M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11036
/dev/loop1       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop3      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop5       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/11107
/dev/loop4       52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/sda5       823G  716G   65G  92% /home
tmpfs           2.4G   28K  2.4G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Results of `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1988
loop1    7:1    0  64.8M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop2    7:2    0  31.1M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11036
loop3    7:3    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop4    7:4    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/518
loop5    7:5    0  32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11107
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  95.4G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
─sda5    8:5    0 836.1G  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0   3.7T  0 disk
```

My PhD career is based on data inside it. Please help to restore my data.

Comment: FYI:  A format is the creation of a new partition table, meaning it takes almost no time to destroy the highest level part of what's stored on the disk. Your system could continue using it because parts of the lost data were *cached* in RAM and it thus wasn't reading that data off the disk (the moment it was read you'll have noted IO errors).  On reboot or `umount` the cached data was lost, trying to read the new partition table (which may have been corrupted if it hadn't been allowed to complete; if would have been empty on completion anyway).

Comment: `/dev/sdb` refers to a drive (device), where the partition you mount is usually `sdb1` etc, ie. you mount partitions and not devices/drives.

Comment: as @guiverc pointed out preecisely, I guess i lost/damaged partition of disk as it was formatting comand which i hit accidently  but large chunk of data is still intact. I am running data recovery in Win10 n i can see many files are intact. Is there anyway i can restore partition and os start recognizing my disk? as of now there is no partition as can be seen on lsblk command. i can only see /dev/sdb only.